# How deal with Gothic letters, like $\mathfrak{ A,B,C,D,a,b,c,d}\dots$, when writing by hand?

Tags: soft-question, notation

In mathematics, I sometimes encounter Gothic letters, I mean the letters $\mathfrak A, \mathfrak B, \mathfrak C, \mathfrak D, \dots, \mathfrak a, \mathfrak b, \mathfrak c, \mathfrak d, \dots$.  To get them in $\LaTeX$ one would use `$\mathfrak{A}$` etc.

For example, in the book *Model theory* by Chang and Keisler, structures are denoted $\mathfrak A = (A, \dots)$, $\mathfrak B = (B, \dots)$ and so on.

I would like to know how to write this by hand.

Comment: Possibly related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236303

Comment: @Rob Arthan I don't see how how to write symbols, use a pen, code LaTex, or spell words, could possibly be considered on topic.  And I don't have the slightest idea what the question actually is as the OP clearly does know how to write the symbols.

Comment: Andrew Stacey's article: [Old Pappus' Book of Mathematical Calligraphy](http://loopspace.mathforge.org/CountingOnMyFingers/Calligraphy/) may also be of interest.

Comment: @fleablood: the OP knows how to typeset the symbols using LaTeX, but doesn't know how to write them with a pen. The question is definitely on topic.

Comment: Should this question be deemed off-topic for MSE, please note that  Mathematics Educators Stack Exchange does have a [handful of questions](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/board-use) under the (board-use) tag.

Comment: How on earth can asking how to write symbols with a pen be on topic?  That seems to me to be a perfect example of an unquestionably  off-topic topic.

Comment: @fleablood: so in your view, mathematicians spring into this world fully equipped with all they need to know to use the symbols of mathematics. I don't share your opinion.

Comment: I just think it's a very odd question, and, yes, I have never heard of anyone asking or teaching how to write symbols or letters.  And even if I had, what's there to say?  You put the pen in your hand and you copy the letters.  An art or caligraphy class may help, but I can't conceive of a mathematician being of any use whatsoever.  Did you learn how to write symbols in any math class?

Comment: If this is off-topic, then so is http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1335475/321264. Isn't it?

Comment: @StubbornAtom: perhaps something to ask on Meta, as http://math.stackexchange.com/q/236303/118539, on the other hand, was closed for being off topic.

Comment: @fleablood: did I learn how to write symbols in any maths class? Yes, I did, by watching the teacher writing.

Answer (score 31):

The corresponding handwritten script is [Sütterlinschrift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%BCtterlin) (Sütterlin script). [This chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%BCtterlin#Overview_of_the_letters) (which I’ve now reproduced here) clearly shows you the letter forms.

[image]

**Added 20 October 2022:** Uppercase Sütterlin letters that I have seen used to write mathematics at the blackboard, in some cases by Jerry Keisler, include at least $A,B,G,M,N$, and $U$.

Comment: With all due respect, this is barely intelligible! The "C" looks like a calligraphic "L", the "E" looks like an "f", the "X" looks like a calligraphic "H", etc.

Comment: @DetachedLaconian: That is largely because you’re so familiar with a very different script based on a very different kind of book hand. (And the upper-case *X* looks very much like a standard lower-case *x* in much British handwriting.)

Answer (score 0):

I would probably switch to caligraphic variant for uppercase letters. For lowercase, I personally write it as filled blackboard bold (mostly for $\mathfrak{c}$ as continuum), i.e. you apply the way you write $ℝ, ℂ$ to lowercase letters and fill the space between the doubled stroke. Alternatively, you can also turn the oval-based shape into a hexagonal one.