# Handwriting for Ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am currently studying ring theory, and with that ideals.

A typical occurrence in my textbook might be something like

Let $R$ be a ring, and $\mathfrak{a}\subset R$ an ideal in $R$, with $a\in\mathfrak{a}$, etc..

My question is, how do I write this by hand (on paper)? How do you guys manage to write the "ideal" a ($\mathfrak{a}$) different from the element $a$? Mine always seems to end up looking the same..

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1899334/12042) for script equivalents. However, I would deal with it by using names like $I$ and $J$ for ideals.

Comment: Personally, since I write ordinary text in italics, I write gothic as a gibberish version of my usual lower case and capital letters. $\ddot\smile$